# R "non-random" number simulaton

Tags: r, random, simulation

[image]

This question is in regards to R. I would like to generate a "non-random" sample of 1's and 0's where the next value generated is dependant on the previous value. For example, if the first value in the vector is 1 then there is a 60% chance that next value is 1, and if the next value is a 0, then there is a 60% chance that the following will be 0. I have attached the question as it was posed to me. I greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: `x <- sample(c(0,1),1); vect <- c()
for (i in 1:10000) 
if(x==1){vect[i] <- sample(c(0,1),1,prob=c(.4,.6))
} else if(x==0) {vect[i] <- sample(c(0,1),1,prob=c(.6,.4))
}`

Comment: This is what I had initially but i believe i was not indexing my empty vector correctly in the for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your conditions, I would generate a sequence using `for` loop.

```
set.seed(111)

n = 10000                #As the Q said at least 10,000
seq = vector()
seq[1] = sample(0:1, 1)  #Also given in the Q

for(i in 2:n) {
  if(seq[i-1] == 0){
    seq[i] = sample(0:1, 1 , prob = c(0.6,0.4))
  }
  else{
    seq[i] = sample(0:1, 1 , prob = c(0.4,0.6))
  }
}

table(seq)
seq
0    1 
4961 5039
```

Comment: I believe that's what I'm looking for. I had the initial if else statement  just wasn't initializing the for loop correctly. Thank you for your help